# The following code need slicing to replace all items in a list?

Tags: python, slice

```
def square_please(some_list):
some_list[:] = [x**2 for x in some_list]
```

Hello, why do we need the [:] in our code in order for it to replace every item in the list with its squared value? It is not intuitive to me why we need the slicing at all.

I would think because we are assigning a new list to some_list, it would overwrite the previous list, similar to if we had the following:

```
list1 = [3,4,5]
list1 = [6,7,8]
```

Comment: It will work even if you remove ':'
It is basically used to splice the array by specifying the indexes before and after the ':'

Comment: Why do you even want to slice the list.
Just assign it as you normally do.

Comment: They do two *completely* different things. `a = [3, 4, 5]` assigns *a new list* to the name `a`. The old list that was being referred to by `a` is *not affected directly*. If it *happens* to no longer be referenced, it is garbage collected. `a[:] = [3, 4, 5]` **mutates** the list object being referenced by `a`, and this change will be visible to all other references to that same object (obviously, because it is the same object)

Comment: So, consider, `a = [1, 2]; b = a` then compare what happens if you do `a = [3, 4]; print(b)` versus `a[:] = [3, 4]; print(b)`

Answer (score 2):

If you *do not* use `[:]` it will create an entirely new list and assign it to `some_list` and any previous references to `some_list` will not be modified. In some cases this is not an issue. If you return `some_list` it would return a new list and both the squared and unsquared one could be used, but other times you want to change the value in-place and this is how you would do that.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677275/list-assignment-with/7677417#7677417) question.