# del statement not working for list

Tags: python, arrays, loops, del

I have a long list where each element is a list of length 2. The first element of each is a list is a string and the second element of each list is an integer corresponding to the string.

I want to loop through the long "parent" list and delete any "child" lists where the integer is less than three. This is my code.

```
for i in range(len(fontsizenum) / 2):
   if int(fontsizenum[i][1]) < 3:
      del fontsizenum[i]
```

However, it is not working as when I print the list afterwards, it still contains values with numbers less than three.

Say this is the list that I am altering.

```
fontsizenum = [[cereal, 1], [dog, 4], [cat, 2], [water, 5]]
```

The expected output is `[[dog, 4], [water, 5]]`.

However, the actual output for me right now is still the original, unchanged list.

Comment: can you add an example of the data that makes up the list?

Comment: @AlexZhang Add the new information to your original post. Also, please include the expected result given that input list.

Comment: @AlexZhang Please learn to format code snippets in your question so it is easier to read. Take a look at how I edited your question.

Answer (score 4):

The resulting list still contains unexpected values because you are modifying the list while iterating over it. In almost all cases, you should avoid modifying an iterable while iterating over it.

If you change your code to the following, the resulting list should be what you expect.

```
new_lst = []
for idx, value in enumerate(lst):
    if value[1] >= 3:
        new_lst.append(value)
```

As noted in the comments by @AntonvBR, the above snippet can be simplified to the following list comprehension

```
[i for i in lst if i[1] > 3]
```

**Example**

If `lst` is set to

```
[
  ['forbidden', 1],
  ['hath', 1],
  ['causes', 2],
  ['whose', 3],
]
```

then the resulting list will be

```
[['whose', 3]]
```

**Explanation**

My code snippet creates a new list that contains elements from the old list. Notably, this allows us to avoid modifying the old list.

I changed the condition in the if-statement to check whether to *include*, rather than to *exclude*, an element. Finally, if that check is satisfied, then I append the value to the new list.

Comment: This is a useful solution but if you want something that avoids creating a new list I would recommend something like the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037725/5992438)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a simple list comprehension for this:

```
expectedoutput = [i for i in fontsizenum if i[1] >= 3]
```