# How to remove item from a python list in a loop?

Tags: python, list

I tried this code to remove items from a list:

```
x = ["ok", "jj", "uy", "poooo", "fren"]
for item in x:
    if len(item) != 2:
        x.remove(item)
```

Why isn't `"fren"` removed from `x`?

Answer (score 109):

You can't remove items from a list while iterating over it.  It's much easier to build a new list based on the old one:

```
y = [s for s in x if len(s) == 2]
```

Comment: Well, to nitpick: You "can", but you'll get useless results and other containers outright disallow it.

Comment: @delnan: Well, to nitpick even more, you *can* and even get useful results if you iterate over the list in reverse order. But this is probably not faster (and definitely much more confusing) than just creating a new list as Sven suggested.

Comment: Yeah I do it in reverse order, works without copying:

x = len(system_list)  # remove all null entries
for i in range(x-1, -1, -1):
    if not system_list[i]:
        del system_list[i]

Comment: @radtek: Since removing an item from a list is an O(n) operation, that approach has O(n²) worst-case complexity.

Comment: this answer is perfectly working.

Answer (score 49):

hymloth and sven's answers work, but they do not modify the list (the create a new one). If you need the object modification you need to assign to a slice:

```
x[:] = [value for value in x if len(value)==2]
```

However, for large lists in which you need to remove few elements, this is memory consuming, but it runs in O(n).

glglgl's answer suffers from O(n²) complexity, because `list.remove` is O(n).

Depending on the structure of your data, you may prefer noting the indexes of the elements to remove and using the `del` keywork to remove by index:

```
to_remove = [i for i, val in enumerate(x) if len(val)==2]
for index in reversed(to_remove): # start at the end to avoid recomputing offsets
    del x[index]
```

Now `del x[i]` is also O(n) because you need to copy all elements after index `i` (a list is a vector), so you'll need to test this against your data. Still this should be faster than using `remove` because you don't pay for the cost of the search step of remove, and the copy step cost is the same in both cases.

[edit] Very nice in-place, O(n) version with limited memory requirements, courtesy of [@Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach). It uses [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.compress#itertools.compress) which was introduced in python 2.7:

```
from itertools import compress

selectors = (len(s) == 2 for s in x)
for i, s in enumerate(compress(x, selectors)): # enumerate elements of length 2
    x[i] = s # move found element to beginning of the list, without resizing
del x[i+1:]  # trim the end of the list
```

Comment: Here's an in-place O(n) version that only needs O(1) additional memory: http://ideone.com/F10fB.  It isn't any more complex than your O(n^2) version. (+1 for a detailed answer, btw)

Comment: nice one. You should post it as an answer on SO.

Comment: Why would you assign to `x[:]` instead of just `x`?

Comment: The code doesn't really fit in my answer, but it fits well in the discussion in *your* answer.  Care to integrate it?  (Note that `itertools.compress()` was introduced in Python 2.7.)

Comment: @KirkStrauser: To change the semantics to in-place manipulation. see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1208792/279627

Comment: @SvenMarnach OK, so that'd be good for when there are multiple references to `x` (such as the caller of the function we're working with here), right? But in the short term, isn't it still building a second copy of the list in memory then assigning it in-place to `x[:]`, then collecting the old now-unreferenced list?

Comment: @KirkStrauser: Of course, that's the very reason for my first comment to this post.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's what I thought. I think we meant different things by "in-place", and I wanted to make sure Python wasn't using some advanced optimization I didn't know about. Thanks!

Comment: @KirkStrauser: You might be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948293/python-slice-assignment-memory-usage/4948508#4948508) for more details.

Comment: @gurneyalex Thanks for showing the usage of slice x[:] to avoid creation of a new object! I came here looking only for that.

Answer (score 7):

```
x = [i for i in x if len(i)==2]
```

Answer (score 3):

This stems from the fact that on deletion, the iteration skips one element as it semms only to work on the index.

Workaround could be:

```
x = ["ok", "jj", "uy", "poooo", "fren"]
for item in x[:]: # make a copy of x
    if len(item) != 2:
        print "length of %s is: %s" %(item, len(item))
        x.remove(item)
```

Comment: hmm... you are right. So in terms of time, hymloth's and your solutions seem to be the best AFAICT...

Answer (score 2):

The already-mentioned list comprehension approach is probably your best bet. But if you absolutely want to do it in-place (for example if `x` is really large), here's one way:

```
x = ["ok", "jj", "uy", "poooo", "fren"]
index=0
while index < len(x):
    if len(x[index]) != 2:
        print "length of %s is: %s" %(x[index], len(x[index]))
        del x[index]
        continue
    index+=1
```