# Does [ : ] create a copy of the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, memory, slice

My code is as follows:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
k = 3
k = k % len(nums)
nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]
```

Does [ : ] create a copy of the list?

In that case, is extra memory allocated if I use this code? Is it O(1)?

Comment: Regardless of whether extra memory is allocated (yes, it is, but for the temporary result of `+`, not for `nums[:]`), it should be clear that the code cannot be O(1) because it needs to move each one of the elements of `num`. So it's O(N) (where N is the size of `num`), and the only question is what the constant multiplier might be.

Answer (score -3):

`[:]` does create a copy.

```py
# data
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x[:]

# changing x value
x[0] = 2

# checking out the results
print(x, y)
```

> `[2,2,3] [1,2,3]`

Check out [Python Slice Assignment Memory Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948293/python-slice-assignment-memory-usage)